# how implement function work as sprintf use wchar for parameter？

Tags: printf, wchar

l used ANDROID NDK 。so l want to format something。just use sprintf，but l can not use it with 
wchar_t. is there some helps for me？

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [swprintf](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_wprintf.htm) and friends, assuming Android has it like Posix and Linux systems.

Glib (from [GTK](http://gtk.org/)) has functions for [unicode manipulation](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html) and for [string utilities](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html). I believe you should be able to make it work on Android.

Comment: yes.but the NDK maybe not implemant this function,so l want to implemant a function like swprintf.

Comment: If NDK don't provide it, I suggest to use a library providing similar functions, such as Glib (from http://gtk.org/ ...)

Comment: glib use trio for g_snprintf function,but trio just provide for char ,do not support wide char,

Answer (score 1):

In Android OS NDK versions before 5.0 ("Lollipop"), the sprintf() does not support the "%ls" (wchar_t pointer) format specifier.  Thus, the following statement compiles but does not execute correctly under NDK (pre-5.0):

```
char buffer [1000];
wchar_t *wp = L"wide-char text";

sprintf (buffer, "My string is: %ls", wp);
```

The workaround is to convert the wchar_t string to UTF-8 (which is a char *) using any one of the Open Source wide-to-utf8 implementations (e.g. [the UTF8-CPP project](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)), passing its pointer to sprintf:

```
// WcharToUtf8: A cross-platform function I use for converting wchar_t string
//              to UTF-8, based on the UTF8-CPP Open Source project
bool WcharToUtf8 (std::string &dest, const wchar_t *src, size_t srcSize)
{
    bool ret = true;

    dest.clear ();

    size_t wideSize = sizeof (wchar_t);

    if (wideSize == 2)
    {
        utf8::utf16to8 (src, src + srcSize, back_inserter (dest));
    }
    else if (wideSize == 4)
    {
        utf8::utf32to8 (src, src + srcSize, back_inserter (dest));
    }
    else
    {
        // sizeof (wchar_t) is not 2 or 4 (does it equal one?)!  We didn't 
        // expect this and need to write code to handle the case.
        ret = false;
    }

    return ret;
}
...
char buffer [1000];
wchar_t wp = L"wide-char text";
std::string utf8;

WcharToUtf8 (utf8, wp, wcslen (wp));
sprintf (buffer, "My string is: %s", utf8.c_str ());
```

Starting with Android 5.0 ("Lollipop"), sprintf() supports the "%ls" format specifier, so the original sprintf() code above works correctly.

If your Android NDK code needs to run on all version of Android, you should wrap all your wchar_t pointers passed to sprintf with a macro like the following:

```
#define CONVERTFORANDROID(e) (GetSupportsSprintfWideChar () ? (void *) e : (void *) WcharToUtf8(e).c_str ())

char buffer [1000];
wchar_t *wp = L"wide-char text";

sprintf (buffer, "My string is: %ls", CONVERTFORANDROID(wp));
```

The GetSupportsSprintfWideChar() function should be a local function that returns true if the running Android OS is 5.0 or above, while returning false if the OS is pre-5.0.