# swprintf() doesn't work on Android Kitkat and below?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, wchar-t

Most of the time I use UTF-8 on Android but I'm recently testing `wchar_t` too.
I know `wchar_t` was horrible in the early days, but I don't care about too old devices so thought it would be fine to work with `wchar_t` now.

Tested on:

Physical devices: Samsung Galaxy Note2 (4.4.2), Galaxy S7 Edge (7.0)

Software emulators: HTC One (4.3), Samsung Galaxy S6 (5.0, 6.0), S8 (7.0), Google Pixel C (7.1.0)

In my simple tests, `wcslen()`, `wcscpy()`, `wcscat()` worked as expected,
but `swprintf()` did nothing on **HTC One** (4.3) and **Note2**(4.4.2).
I couldn't test all the devices out there, but my conclusion is that `swprintf()` just doesn't work on Android Kitkat and below. It may just return doing nothing.

Could someone confirm my theory, please? Is there any workaround for this?

Whether practical or not, I just want to know.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136843/how-implement-function-work-as-sprintf-use-wchar-for-parameter

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Thanks for the comment but I read it already and that's about **sprintf()**.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ask me why, but until L Android only had a stub implementation of `vswprintf` that just returns -1.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/kitkat-release/libc/bionic/wchar.cpp#74

The workaround would be to use libandroid_support. This is automatic if you're using libc++ (and that's the best option for NDK r16+).